# How to scale mongodb official docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker, scalability

I've been trying to scale the official docker container with docker swarm. But how I handle data persistence in `stack.yml` file.

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

I tried this stack configuration with `volumes`. But it's not working.

How can I tackle it?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you add whatever error you're facing or unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is what you should be doing if you want to scale up your mongodb microservice. You might need to look into how sharding can be implemented when mongodb is running in a docker container.